# Let user to add input fields on theme option page

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, theme-options

I'm creating a Theme Option page for my own wordpress theme and I've been trying to create something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4m50qjw51qvzaf/Untitled.png?dl=0) on my option page

It means my user(admin) can add any number of input fields (in this image, they're drop down elements)

I need to add this feature as a inbuilt option page, so plugins like ACF will not work for me in this case. I have to build this from scratch.

Thanks...

Comment: Please read hhttp://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic .. this question is not suitable for any site. You must try to solve the issue, supply the code where you are stuck and what you tried to so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the following class in your theme for admin options;

[Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Using-CMB-to-create-an-Admin-Theme-Options-Page)

And you can call your repeatable fields with some thing like this;

```
    array(
        'name' => 'Name of field',
        'id'   => 'prefix_option_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'default'  => '',
        'repeatable' => true,
    ),
```

For more details on how to use this class you can go through following [documentation](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Field-Types) and [example code](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/blob/master/example-functions.php).